# Error converting data type varchar to bigint when trying to concatenate column row values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that I am using to concatenate the row values of a column into a single value.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
        ( 
            SELECT
                ',' + id_number AS 'data()'
            FROM
                users FOR XML PATH('')
        ),
        2,
        9999
    ) AS id_numbers
```

The id_number column is of type varchar. I have tried to convert to text but still getting errors.

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server 2008?  It is no longer supported.  And why would you want to change perfect good `varchar()` to deprecated `text`?

Comment: waiting on infrastructure to upgrade! not seen as a priority as the server is on the internal network only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id_number` is a `bigint`, you'll need to `CONVERT` or `CAST` it to a text type:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
        ( 
            SELECT
                ',' + CONVERT( varchar(20), id_number ) AS 'data()'
            FROM
                users FOR XML PATH('')
        ),
        2,
        9999
    ) AS id_numbers
```

[If you're using SQL Server 2017 or later you can use `STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (MS SQL Server's equivalent to MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`):

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG( id_number, ', ' )
```

(SQL Server will handle the implicit `bigint`-to-`varchar` conversion for you as there's no ambiguousness introduced by the use of binary operators).

Comment: Limited to sql server 2008 at the minute :-(

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.